# What would be an appropriate phrase that indicates something has been used too much

Tags: phrases, expressions

For example, let's say someone describes a simple physical theory and uses mathematics heavily in their description, in such a way that it makes the whole description quite confusing.

I want to say something like, "s/he has beaten the shit out of mathematics in her/his description" to indicate they have used mathematics unnecessarily much.

What would be possible phrases that can be used in such a situation.

I'm looking more for slang than formal language.

Comment: As you imply, the description is heavy on the maths.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I'll be writing to a close friend; so using such a language not a problem

Comment: @marcellothearcane see my edit please

Comment: Synonyms for [***superfluous***](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/superfluous) include, for example, ***redundant, unnecessary, unrequired, inessential, gratuitous, needless, pleonastic, tautological, dispensable,...*** Take your pick.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I am not looking for a word, I am looking for a phrase, like a saying.

Comment: So just use "beat the shit out of". Or some slightly less crude alternative, such as "flogged the guts / living daylights out of".

Comment: What's *wrong* with the single word [**overused**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overused)? Why do you require a phrase instead?

Comment: Went overboard with the math?

Comment: `excessive usage`, `redundant` Example: `She/He has done excessive use of mathematics in her/his description.` or `So much usage of mathematics was redundant in her/his description.`

Comment: I would focus on learning standard English. [ell.se] might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Taking a sledgehammer to crack a nut**

would seem appropriate.

See [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/a-sledgehammer-to-crack-a-nut) for explanation.

Comment: Or "killing a mosquito with a baseball bat": using a much bigger or more complex system for a small problem that could be dealt with much more simply.

Comment: @Conrado What is a baseball bat?

Comment: Sorry, my false step; I was born in North America. A baseball bat is a kind of club used in a game there. Here's a picture: http://probaseballinsider.com/best-hitters-consistent-every-year/

Comment: @Conrado — I was only joking. I lived in Chicago for three years. “Take me to the ball game.”

Comment: Me: https://imgflip.com/memetemplate/92782447/forehead-slap; ALSO https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3b/Paris_Tuileries_Garden_Facepalm_statue.jpg/300px-Paris_Tuileries_Garden_Facepalm_statue.jpg . Still, It's safest to take all questions seriously when I don't know who I'm talking to. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

How about **over the top**? From Lexico:

> **[over the top](https://www.lexico.com/definition/over_the_top)**: To an excessive or exaggerated degree.

Your example:

> S/he was **over the top** in her use of mathematics to describe X.

For extra emphasis, you could say s/he was **way over the top**.

Comment: I think I'm looking for much of a slang language

Comment: @onurcanbektas, You've never mentioned *slang* in your question.

Comment: @onurcanbektas How about **over the frigging top**? You’re free to choose a more objectionable adjective.

Answer (score 0):

You could say that that person has **belabored** the mathematics in the description.

> **belabor** *vt*
>
> 1. to explain, worry about, or work at unduly: *belaboring an obvious point*
>    <sub>[TFD Online](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/belabor)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

*'Theory X is flooded with math jargon'* might be the sort of informal phrase you're looking for.